# Could not initialize DefaultJasperReportsContext, Jasper Studio error after upgrading

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

After upgrading to the latest version of Jaspersoft Studio (6.5)

If I try to compile a report targeted at a previous JasperREports library version (5.6.1) I encounter the error

```
Could not initialize net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext
```

I have the project settings set as follows

[image]

I'm on linux.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Did you remove the old version of JSS completely? Does it work for 6.0 version (not for 5.6.1)? Does it work if you are compiling report as is (without using Compatibility mode)?

Comment: Yes, the old version is gone. It's a fresh install of ubuntu. And yes, it works compiling to 6+ version.